# Python: Why doesn't my code work?

Tags: python, scripting

I am on using Blender 2.8 Beta.

In this code, I am creating a particle system for the active object, and the particles are the rest of the selection.

```
import bpy

A = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
A.select_set(state=False)

def find_collection(context, item):
    collections = item.users_collection
    if len(collections) > 0:
        return collections[0]
    return context.scene.collection

def make_collection(collection_name, parent_collection):
    if collection_name in bpy.data.collections:
        return bpy.data.collections[collection_name]
    else:
        new_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
        parent_collection.children.link(new_collection)
        return new_collection

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    o_collection = find_collection(bpy.context, o)
    new_collection = make_collection(bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01", o_collection)
    new_collection.objects.link(o)
    o_collection.objects.unlink(o)

bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
A.modifiers[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"
A.particle_systems[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"
bpy.data.particles[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"
bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"].type = 'HAIR'
bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"].render_type = 'COLLECTION'
bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"].instance_collection = bpy.data.collections[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"]
```

It works fine once, but I want to reuse my code multiple times, so after creating the first particle system, I want to create particlesystem 02, 03, 04, 05...

I found how to do this with this code, that creates a mirror modifier, and it's working great!!!

```
import bpy 

A = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
if "QuickMirror1" not in A.modifiers:
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MIRROR')
    A.modifiers[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = "QuickMirror1"
    bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='CUBE')
    bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.01, 1, 1), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='ENABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=0.00439353)
    E = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
    E.name = "Mirror1"
    A.modifiers["QuickMirror1"].mirror_object = E
if "QuickMirror1" in A.modifiers:
    if "QuickMirror2" not in A.modifiers:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MIRROR')
        A.modifiers[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = "QuickMirror2"
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='CUBE')
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.01, 1, 1), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='ENABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=0.00439353)
        E = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        E.name = "Mirror2"
        A.modifiers["QuickMirror2"].mirror_object = E
if "QuickMirror2" in A.modifiers:
    if "QuickMirror3" not in A.modifiers:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MIRROR')
        A.modifiers[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = "QuickMirror3"
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='CUBE')
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.01, 1, 1), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='ENABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=0.00439353)
        E = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        E.name = "Mirror3"
        A.modifiers["QuickMirror3"].mirror_object = E
```

I use the if statements. If 01 doesn't exist, create it, 
if 01 exists and 02 doesn't, create 02, if 02 exists and 03 doesn't, create 03... Repeat until you think it's necessary...
Is there maybe a better way to do this in Python? If there is, could you please explain it to me simply, I am a beginner, the code here is all I know about Python.

I was using the exact same method with this code with my auto particle:

```
import bpy

A = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
A.select_set(state=False)

def find_collection(context, item):
    collections = item.users_collection
    if len(collections) > 0:
        return collections[0]
    return context.scene.collection

def make_collection(collection_name, parent_collection):
    if collection_name in bpy.data.collections:
        return bpy.data.collections[collection_name]
    else:
        new_collection = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
        parent_collection.children.link(new_collection)
        return new_collection

if bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01" not in A.modifiers:
    for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        o_collection = find_collection(bpy.context, o)
        new_collection = make_collection(bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01", o_collection)
        new_collection.objects.link(o)
        o_collection.objects.unlink(o)

    bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
    A.modifiers[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"
    A.particle_systems[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"
    bpy.data.particles[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"
    bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"].type = 'HAIR'
    bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"].render_type = 'COLLECTION'
    bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"].instance_collection = bpy.data.collections[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01"]


if bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle01" in A.modifiers:
    if bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02" not in A.modifiers:
        for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            o_collection = find_collection(bpy.context, o)
            new_collection = make_collection(bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02", o_collection)
            new_collection.objects.link(o)
            o_collection.objects.unlink(o)

        bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
        A.modifiers[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02"
        A.particle_systems[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02"
        bpy.data.particles[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02"
        bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02"].type = 'HAIR'
        bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02"].render_type = 'COLLECTION'
        bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02"].instance_collection = bpy.data.collections[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02"]

if bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle02" in A.modifiers:
    if bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03" not in A.modifiers:
        for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            o_collection = find_collection(bpy.context, o)
            new_collection = make_collection(bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03", o_collection)
            new_collection.objects.link(o)
            o_collection.objects.unlink(o)

        bpy.ops.object.particle_system_add()
        A.modifiers[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03"
        A.particle_systems[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03"
        bpy.data.particles[len(A.modifiers)-1].name = bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03"
        bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03"].type = 'HAIR'
        bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03"].render_type = 'COLLECTION'
        bpy.data.particles[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03"].instance_collection = bpy.data.collections[bpy.context.active_object.name + "Particle03"]
```

But it create the three particle systems at the same time!!! 
It seams so illogical to me! It worked totally fine for my mirror example, it work fine with this example too, but Blender just decided to ignore my condition for a certain reason. I can't understand why.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Selected objects are not ordered `bpy.context.selected_objects[0]` may be any object out of selected objects. It makes more sense to use the active object instead - `bpy.context.object`.  You should stop thinking about solving every possibility separately in the code. It is better to make a rule that applies to everything. Also please be more specific about your goals in questions - it's still not very clear what you want to do exactly. You will get a lot better help if people do not need to guess what you want.

Comment: Active object will not always be the first object in selected objects list and that will not always be the last or the first object that was selected. Test it if you do not believe me. You can try various ways of selecting a few objects and type C.object and C.selected_objects in the Python Console. You will see the selected_objects list order has nothing to do with the order you select objects in. While it might not be very nice or right of batFINGER to loose his temper, personally I kind of understand that. A few detailed answers were given already that you do not seem to learn from much.

Comment: Oh, and Dorian Borremans, please do follow batFINGER's advice on getting "Python for Dummies" or something similar. You can get a lot of good stuff just simply on www.python.org. You absolutely need to get yourself familiar with the basics of the language: syntax, most basic concepts like variable types, what those brackets mean and stuff like that. It is not terribly difficult and it will certainly pay off and it will not feel like a waste of time for people to dedicate their time and give you detailed examples here once they see you understand them.

Comment: Im learning and im doing my best, that's not nice of you, if you want to recommend me books or tutorials for newbies, please go ahead, but mocking beginners that's just lame.

Comment: Thanks MartinZ I will, and to be clear I didn't want to correct you in my old deleted comment like batdinger suggest, I was just not understanding your proposition, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rehash of my answer to mirror example**

[image]
*Running script 3 times on Cube*

IMO Chaining ifs as in Q code is horrendously awful.

Create x1 cos it doesn't exist, then oh  x1 exists better create x2 in next if, then oh x2 exists better create x3 in next if.  Possibly could  be if, elif, elif.

Similarly to my answer to   [your mirror example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125046/how-to-add-and-use-renamed-mirror-modifier-with-python)  Find an available name, then proceed.

Works  for any number of modifiers. Do you really want to stick to an endless if statement for 10 or 1000 modifiers?

If you don't understand something  ask a question via comments..

Prior answer edited for particle systems.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context # 
scene = context.scene
ob = context.object

i = 0
pref = "%s_Psys" % ob.name

# give it a name based on count of mods.
name = "%s%d" % (pref, i)
while ob.modifiers.get(name):    
    i += 1
    name = "%s%d" % (pref, i)

m = ob.modifiers.new(name, type='PARTICLE_SYSTEM')
ps = m.particle_system
ps.name = name
ps.settings.name = name # bpy.data.pa..
ps.settings.type = 'HAIR'
ps.settings.render_type = 'COLLECTION'
# add collection code.
#ps.settings.collection = blah
```

Add in your collection code.