# Python scripting, shows 'nonetype' error for modifier

Tags: scripting, add-on

```
import bpy


def main(context):    
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='ARRAY')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"].relative_offset_displace[0] = 10
    

    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array"].count = 4
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='ARRAY')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array.001"].relative_offset_displace[1] = 2
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array.001"].relative_offset_displace[0] = 0

    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Array.001"].count = 4

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"


    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I want to add sphere and array modifier, error at line 10

Comment: Recommend  `mod = ob.modifiers.new(name, type)`  example https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/125098/15543  Then there is no need to guess at the modifiers name.  (if using op will be last one added if successful. `new_mod = ob.modifiers[-1]`)

Comment: sry I don't understand, elaborate pls